# Nuxtjs failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

Tags: nginx, websocket, server, centos7, nuxt.js

I setup my nuxt on centOs 7 and I use nginx as server when I run npm run dev on server and open chrome it show me in console this:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.mydomain.com/_loading/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

and try to reconnect again then same error show,
what is the problem?
is it caused by nginx or nuxtjs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detected the issue,
It was caused by centOs server it needs to upgrade its kernel 
I do upgrade the centOs and upgrade its kernel and every thing seems Okay